# Adding a new CRS to QGIS 3.10 with custom coordinate reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I am using a Shapefile of which the projection is not recognized by QGIS. The .prj file of the shapefile has the following information:

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

I want to add this custom coordinate reference system, but I can't get it to work. My parameters are validated, but the "name" keeps causing an error (see added picture) [image: problem with custom coordinate reference system]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: do you know what projection it should be in? is there a .prj file? or any metadata?

Comment: To detect an unknown crs, [Projfinder](http://projfinder.com/) can be a useful tool.

Comment: If there's a .prj file with the .shp file then open it in a text editor or Word and show the contents in your message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps, there was a prj file with the following message:  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Comment: Can you see from this which projection it should be?

Comment: @Spacedman it would be great if you could help me with the contant of the prj. file. Please let me know if you can help me out!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that projection, if I make something with that PRJ it works for me. Its standard lat-long - even with coords out of range I don't get an error. If you edit your question and add that text to it it will improve your question and bump it so more people may see it. If you can supply the full set of shapefile parts (.shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj) then that will help debugging - if you can't share your data then a subset? I can only guess that there's some invisible characters in there or your QGIS (what version? edit and add) is broken.